# Why can't I import an SVG by using <use> without using the id?

Tags: html, svg

Whenever I import an SVG with `<use>` element it won't work unless I specify the id of that SVG even though it's the only SVG in the document!

This will work after specifying an `id="shap"` in the SVG file:

```xml
<svg className="home__social-icon-leetcode">
    <use xlinkHref="svg/shap.svg#shap"></use>
</svg>
```

This won't work even though the SVG file doesn't contain more than one SVG:

```
<svg className="home__social-icon-leetcode">
    <use xlinkHref="svg/shap.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Because that's how [the `href` attribute is defined in the specification](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseElement).

Answer (score 0):

This is an external source usage of [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG), so you must provide the bit you're looking for (The id in the svg file) in the external svg source. Refer to [this](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) link.

Answer (score 0):

`use xlinkHref` has been deprecated, use `use href`

Anyways, both of them has been design to use with a inline svg (inside your HTML) so you can call the same SVG multiple times without having to repeat the SVG code, that's why you need to call their ID.